# PHP file_get_contents how to get <pre> content

Tags: php, httpresponse, file-get-contents

I am trying to work with an API to get some public company data.

An example API URL is the following: https://www.kbo.party/api/v1/enterprise/825386460

As you can see, at the bottom of the page there is a `<pre></pre>` tag with the actual content I am trying to retrieve.

With the following code, I'm able to remotely get the page content, but how could I retrieve an array with just the raw data presented on the page?

```
$search=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['search']);

$api_key = 'xxxxxxxx';
$api_url = 'https://www.kbo.party/api/v1/enterprise/'.$search.'?key='.$api_key;

$response = file_get_contents($api_url);

http_response_code(200);
echo print_r($response,true);
```

Comment: I think the `<pre>` tag is to verify the data. There should be another method or param to get data as JSON.

Comment: Wait, it's JSON data. You can call it.

Comment: By adding `Accept: text/json` header, you can fetch the json.

Comment: Thanks guys, adding the json header worked! Added the working solution as an answer.

Comment: Why is this tagged with AJAX, bud does not contain any such code? Also, keep in mind that `mysqli_real_escape_string` should not be used anywhere, especially not for escaping characters in an API call

Comment: @NicoHaase the code is the PHP of an ajax-call, but you're right, I removed the AJAX tag. Regarding `the mysqli_real_escape_string`, what else should I use for escaping characters then?

Comment: It depends on the use case: for URLs, you should use `urlencode`, as you want to escape things differently than for inserting it into a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Abdulla Nilam and Shingo, I was able to get the following working code:

```
$search=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['search']);

$api_key = 'xxxxxxx';
$api_url = 'https://www.kbo.party/api/v1/enterprise/'.$search.'?key='.$api_key;

$options = array(
'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'header'=>  "Accept: text/json"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($api_url, false, $context );

$response = json_decode($result, 1);

http_response_code(200);
echo print_r($response,true);
```